# Bluemix Presence Insight is depreciated

Tags: ibm-cloud, presenceinsights

Bluemix Presence Insight is depreciated on 3 June so my question is whether i can use it from now onwards on regular basis and if not then is there any alternative of Presence Insight tool which can be used in mobile app???

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to continue to use your provisioned Presence Insights instance regularly until June 3rd 2017 at which point all instances of PI will be deleted. Please note that you will not be able to provision new instances of PI after July 3rd 2016.

Here's the [deprecation announcement in our documents](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/presenceinsights/index.html) that goes over both of your questions.

[image]

There is a clarification to the statement above. Free instances will be deleted on September 3, 2016. Paid instances are supported until June 3, 2017.

With regards to software offered by your location sensor hardware provider we recommend [taking a look at the systems supported by PI](https://presenceinsights.ibmcloud.com/pidocs/docs/en/introduction/intro_architecture/#supported-location-service-provider-systems) which support mobile.

And with regards to IBM Global Technology Services you can take a look at the [Enterprise-level Mobility Services](http://www-935.ibm.com/services/us/en/it-services/enterprise-mobility/index.html) if that fits your needs.